# Automate cabal configure

Tags: haskell, configuration, cabal

If I modify anything in my project's cabal file, and I run `cabal build`, I get:

```
./project-foo.cabal has been changed. Re-configuring with most
recently used options. If this fails, please run configure manually.
```

However, I want certain options like `--enable-executable-profiling` to be turned on by default when I do this. Is this possible and how?

Comment: If you run `cabal configure` with `--enable-executable-profiling` the first time, it will remember your choice and use it for reconfiguring. That's what the "Re-configuring with most recently used options." line refers to.

Comment: You can also add a `cabal.config` file in the same directory as the `.cabal` file and add `enable-executable-profiling` to that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it in a "cabal.config" file in the project folder, with the same structure as the user folder ".cabal/config".

Look for the option in .cabal/config and add it uncommented to your project "cabal.config" file.

Manual: Look for "cabal.config" in this [cabal guide page](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#sandboxes-basic-usage)

It works for a cabal sandboxed project. Not sure about non sandboxed ones.